# Why is it giving an error, "R.layout.dialog cannot be resolved"?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

Here's my layout in XML file **main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView android:text="hello, world" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is Activity code:

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog box");

        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  
                dialog.dismiss();            
            }  
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

basically, I want to run a test program of dialog window which displays something on Startup but I am getting **R.layout.dialog cannot be resolved** at line `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);`
What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: the name of the xml file is dialog.xml right?

Comment: Is your file named layout/dialog.xml? Did you try to clean the environment to create a clean build? Did you modify R manually?

Comment: dialog.xml does not exist => not able to load.

Comment: I perform Clean Project in Eclipse, and then clicked on Build Project but still the same error remains :/

Comment: you have to name it dialog.xml or you need to call R.layout.main

Comment: @Raz Hey, got it. Just modified as `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);` because main is the name of my xml file. Thanks buddies.. 
I am new to android :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the one main layout.you made another name dialog.xml.it will be remove the error.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="hello, world" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="OK" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```